# Operating system tooltip in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do you use the operating system's tooltip utility in Flash with Actionscript 3? An analogous invokation of the OS tooltip is in HTML's anchor tag:

```
<a href="foo.html" title="awesome website">click</a>
```

I don't want to draw my own custom tooltip because **(A)** it will look inconsistent across operating systems, **(B)** long tooltips wouldn't be able to float out of the SWF, and **(C)** it takes time to program (whether to align left or right depending on how close you are to a boundary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use your `<a href="foo.html" title="awesome website">click</a>` as `TextField.htmlText`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Flash alone.  But you could use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_de/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) and JavaScript to set the [title property](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/toolmsg.shtml) of the Flash player object/embed element.

**Edit:**

I Just thought of another one:  Your ExternalInterface call could have any object's bounds as parameters, which you could then use to superimpose an empty transparent gif or png with the appropriate title via JavaScript. The drawback would be that you'd have to have a back channel to forward mouse events, and change the behavior of your Flash controls to ensure your UI works correctly (mouseOver and mouseOut would no longer work as expected, once the image is on top of the Flash player).  But you'd be able to specify more than one tooltip at a time over the plugin, as part of a more fine-grained layout.

Comment: Setting the title attribute on the Flash object did not make the tooltip appear when hovered over (at least in FF3 Win7).

Comment: For FF it should be the `<embed>`-element.  What is your wmode setting?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from Flash.

there are tricks to make them get it to work, but if **C** is anything to go by, that's not what you want to do.

You can do this using AIR, but it looks like you're using swf, so no AIR.

Therefoer I recommend you either find a library that does this, or get a javascript to output the messages using an External Interface Call

Answer (score 0):

what about use the buttonMode(and useHandCursor) property for sprite / movieclip subclasses? This is basically the same behavior a user expects from an html anchor tag as it shows the native hand cursor.

It is easy to replace the default cursor and substitute with a displayObject of your own, but that is never a good user experience in my opinion.

hope this helps.

-philip